# Google Analytics tool

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track my app usage using the Google Analytics tool. But my Google Analytics account shows no visis/visitors. I have used my app several times. I have set the button click event as well. But it shows nothing. I have got a valid key as well.

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GoogleAnalysis extends Activity {

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker mGATracker;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* try{ mGATracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
         mGATracker.startNewSession(" UA-xxxxx-x", this);
         mGATracker.trackPageView( "/SettingsMangerActivity" ); } catch(
         Exception error ) { Log.e( "<YOUR_TAG>", "onCreate: " +
         error.toString() ); }
         */

        tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        tracker.startNewSession(" UA-30927539-1", this);
        setContentView(R.layout.googleanlytics);

        Button createEventButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
        createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tracker.trackPageView("/SettingsMangerActivity");
                tracker.trackEvent("Clicks", "Button", "Share Files", 0);

            }
        });

        Button createPageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
        createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Navigation Type", "Button click", 2);
                tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
            }
        });

        Button quitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
        quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

```
    Button dispatchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
    dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was
            // started with a dispatch
            // interval.
            tracker.dispatch();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
    tracker.stopSession();
}
```

}

Comment: did you check your permissions to ensure your app can access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

When debugging your App, are you seeing it sending image requests to google-analytics.com

If not, the problem is in the code or app
If yes and it's going to the correct UA-id, check the Real Time Reporting.

If it's not showing up there it's something in the GA configuration like a filter that's blocking the data entering the filter.

If you have filters on your reporting View, create another that has no filters.

Let us now how that goes